# htaccess: Redirect, but not if folder-root or index.html (prevent looping)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am fighting with htaccess and I found some pages where my case is discussed - but not exactly, so I need help.

I have a login-system on my webpages with php. So every .html page, before it will be delivered, has to be send to a php-script which is testing if the user is logged in, on success forward to the requested .html page, instead to the login page (index.html).

I have different language-folders and put my .htaccess in the root of all those folders, and I would love to have only one .htaccess for all folders.

Folder structure:

/members-manager/web/$country/ *HERE IS .htaccess*

This is how I made already successful the forward to check the login, but I got a loop:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ members-manager/service/validate-user-login-for-url.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Any tipps?

Thank you !!

**-------------UPDATE, to be more specific on the problem:-------------**

I better describe the process:

URL (e.g. "www.domain.com/members-manager/web/en/launch.html")

=>

.htaccess: -> Forward to PHP to verify login

=>

members-manager/service/validate-user-login-for-url.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI}

=>

PHP: Is user logged in? If yes: Forward back to original url(%{REQUEST_URI})

=>

URL(%{REQUEST_URI})

STOP.

BUT: My .htaccess rewrite-rule again matches, and so a loop is going on :-(
How can I write a condition to do not rewrite the url again after it "comes from" the php script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correct then you have .htaccess file in every "country" folder, to avoid that loop you just need to add / at beginning of your path

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /members-manager/service/validate-user-login-for-url.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

But probably much better solution will be if you put just one .htaccess file in your root folder and add this rule to that .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^members-manager/web/(.+)/(.+)$ members-manager/service/validate-user-login-for-url.php?url=members-manager/web/$1/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi ban17, sorry for my late answer, I really wanted to try out what you wrote. And thanks, the idea with the more global .htaccess is much better, did it! But I found out I need to be more specific: I guess problem is, that my loop comes by the php redirecting with "header: $original-url" to find a correct condition, so the .htaccess rewrite-rule is not again forwarding and so the loop goes on. Any idea on that? Is my question clearly explained? If not I add code-examples... Thanks already!

Comment: I updated my original question, with a more concret description.

Comment: You can add     

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !members-manager/service/validate-user-login-for-url.php`   

before RewriteRule line. I'm not sure if something more missing.

Comment: **GREAT!!!!** Now it works, I can't believe!! You made my day, thanks a LOT !!! :-) Thanks thanks thanks!!